# How to convert Object to Jooq JSON

Tags: json, jackson, wrapper, jooq

I have a String (jsonData) being mapped to json via Jackson Object mapper as below to JaxB.

```
var completeJson = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, Data.class);
myDto.setFirstName(completeJson.getFirstName())
myDto.setLastName(completeJson.getLastName()))
.....
.....etc..etc
```

I'm able to map to the above strings just fine.  However, I'm having problems mapping
to a jooq JSON object.  I guess I will now have to convert jsonData to jooq JSON.

How would I do this?

```
JSON newJson = objectMapper.(best method to use);

myDto.setJsonSource(newJson)
```

Or maybe I have to create some sort of wrapper?

DTO configured by jooq

```
public myDto setJsonSource(JSON jsonSource) {
    this.jsonSource = jsonSource;
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`org.jooq.JSON`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/JSON.html) type is just a wrapper around a string, so why not just use:

```java
JSON json = JSON.json(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object));
```